# Kinda confused about my career

Tags: job-change, developer

This is the first time I'm posting and also peeking at this site ; so please spare me if I'm wrong with the question formats.

I'm a software developer in a insurance tech company. Mainly doing development with Oracle PL SQL and XML. Almost reaching two years of experience. I was thinking of switching my job but how to start with it?

I casually surfed net for the jobs and I see minimum 3 years of experience needed for any PL SQL developer jobs.

Here's another thing that catching me, I was thinking of learning web development on free time and switch domain as I find it more interesting than PL SQL. But at the same time switching domains is kinda risky and I would have to take up a entry level job.

So should I continue with PL SQL route or go for a web dev job. Or is there anything where I can put both skills at work?

w.r.t. web dev I already know basics of HTML , CSS , JavaScript, PHP , LAMP , and Bootstrap.

Comment: It will not let me post for some reason.

Comment: "switching domains is kinda risky" it's not risky at all. Besides, you'll never lose from going ahead and learning. Don't think about it, do it. That being said, yes, you will have to have knowledge in all of this for certain positions. I write Web APIs in the backend, I write React web clients and I have to know how to interact with the database on various levels.

Comment: I feel it might be a bit of a stretch for your situation, but [might this be](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/172990/125897) a helpful angle?

Comment: Thank you @Jonast92, I think I needed that.

Comment: @Levente yes, it did help me get a better perspective.

Comment: My current job as a junior required something like 3-5 years of experience and I was hired with less than 1 in development (ignoring degrees). Years of experience are pretty much meaningless if you fit the company. Apply anyway.

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque that's kind of eye opener in the past few days with me surfing jobs. All the requirements seems so cookie cutter know it all types. Thank you for your suggestion I'll apply for them anyways and see how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

If you already know you'll enjoy web development more, just go for it (especially since you already know the basics). Especially since you're still early on in your career. It's always risky to switch jobs, even within the same field, but if you never take the risk, you won't get anywhere and remain stuck in the same job forever.

And in my experience the 3 year experience required is more a formality than anything. Just apply if you think your skills are good enough for the job listed. Chances are that if you can convince them of that, they'll hire you. Of course, if they're really strict with the 3 year experience, they won't hire you, but you won't know until you apply.